# How to make orthogonal edges with cytoscape.js

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I have a basic example working with cytoscape.js, which looks like this:

[image: current output]

Notice how all the edges start and end from the center of the nodes.  I'd like to make orthogonal edges which start from the center-right point of the source node and end at the center-left point of the target node.  Something like this:

[image: desired output]

I've only made a couple sample edges but you get the idea.  As a bonus, it would be nice if the lines also had rounded corners.  Even though I'm not making a sitemap, this example I found on the web is another good example of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: sitemap]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the Github issue to track this feature request: https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/359